# Reversing input every two characters

Tags: c

I've been trying to make a program that takes an address and reverses it for every two characters. An example input would be "0xefba5896" and ideally it's output would be "\x96\x58\xba\xef". The trouble I'm getting is that the first few bytes work, but the last one doesn't print. My code is below:

```
     int i;
     char *add =  argv[1];
     char rev[8];
     char xa[2];
     strncpy(rev, &add[2], strlen(add));   
     for (i = strlen(rev) - 2; i > -2; i-=2) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    strncpy(xa, &rev[0], 2);
                 } else {
                    strncpy(xa, &rev[i], 2);
                    xa[2] = '\0';
            }
                printf("\\x%s", xa);
     }
```

If I input "0xefba5896" my output is:

```
\x96\x58\xba\x
```

If the answer is obvious to someone, please forgive me. I've been learning C for only about a week.
Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Do you think this qualifies as a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)? If so, what is it really what you want to do? Change the endianess of an integer?

Comment: `for (i = strlen(rev) - 2; i > -2; i-=2)` — is `rev` the input? It would help if you gave your variables more meaningful names. In any case, what happens when `strlen(rev)` is an odd number?

Comment: Also note, 1. `strncpy()` is a tricky function, it sometimes skips the *null* terminator and most of the times  you can replace it with `memcpy()` if you know what you're doing. 2. You overused `strncpy()`, because to just copy 2 bytes you can as well just do that, assign them directly.

Comment: It makes no sense to pass `strlen(add)` as the limiting factor to `strncpy`, if `add` is longer than 8, you will still overflow `rev`! You have to pass the size of the destination, not the size of the source. So the correct call is `strncpy(rev, add +2, sizeof rev);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to pass `strlen(add)` as the limiting factor to `strncpy`, if `add` is longer than 10,
you will still overflow `rev`!

You have to pass **the size of the destination**, not the size of the source. So the correct call is

```
strncpy(rev, add+2, sizeof rev);
rev[sizeof(rev) - 1] = 0;
```

Also note that `strncpy` does not necessarily write the `'\0'`-terminating byte
if the destination is not long enough, so you should always set the
`'\0'`-terminating byte yourself.

Also note that `xa[2] = '\0';` overflows `xa`, because the size of `xa` is 2, so
the maximal index is `1`. If you want to store 2 characters in `xa`, then
`xa` needs to be of at least dimension 3. Same goes for `rev`. So You have to declare `xa` as this:

```
char rev[9];
char xa[3];
```

So when you use `strncpy`, you should use it like this:

```
char dest[8];
strncpy(dest, src, sizeof dest);
dest[sizeof(dest) - 1] = 0;
```

So you can rewrite your program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s address\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t len;
    char *add =  argv[1];
    char rev[9];
    char xa[3];  

    strncpy(rev, add + 2, sizeof rev);
    rev[sizeof(rev) - 1] = 0;

    len = strlen(rev);

    if(len & 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid length of address, needs an even number of characters\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(size_t i = len - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
    {
        strncpy(xa, rev + i, sizeof xa);
        xa[sizeof(xa) - 1] = 0;

        printf("\\x%s", xa);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As it turns out, all I needed was to extend my arrays by one.